# How to specify preference for compilers when using enable_language [cmake]

Tags: makefile, cmake

When using enable_language in cmake, it always search for compilers in a certain default sequence. I wonder how I can change this sequence. For example, if my system has both ifort (icc) and gfortran (g++) installed, and I want to use ifort (icc) instead of the gfortran (g++), how could I set up this?

CLARIFICATION: I know we can switch the compiler explicitly by changing the variable CMAKE_Fortran_Compiler, but what I want to do is rather to modify the default sequence that cmake searches for available compilers if the user does not specify such a preference.

From what I currently found, a work-around is to set CMAKE_Fortran_Compiler before project(xxx), so that this variable can never gets overridden later, but clearly this is not the best way, since I will need gfortran if there turns out to be no ifort available.

By the way, what's the best place to look for this kind of information? The documentation does not seem to be very complete..

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the tags `c++`, `fortran`, and even `compiler` are appropriate. The question doesn't have anything to do with the languages and their implementations. It's really only about cmake.

Comment: The best place to look for this information is either StackOverflow (grin) or the CMake mailing list. While the Wiki and built-in documentation often have good answers, things like this often get left by the wayside. I've not found any other solution to what you're looking for either.

Answer (score 2):

The right place to look is the CMake FAQ, which [answers your question](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_use_a_different_compiler.3F).

Omegaice's answer will work, as will `CC=/path/to/icc cmake ...`, see also [this discussion thread](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-May/044445.html).

Setting `CMAKE_Fortran_Compiler` before the `project` call is **strongly discouraged** (as the FAQ will tell you).

Note that manually calling `enable_language` is no different from specifying the languages with the `project` call (or indeed not specifying them, in which case they default to *C* and *CXX*), since that calls `enable_language` internally.

Comment: The FAQ does not answer my question. I have clarified my original post   (also as a reply to Omegaice)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably specify which compiler to use by doing `ccmake .. -DCMAKE_Fortran_Compiler=<executable>` (where `<executable>` is either the name of the compiler or the full path to the compiler) instead of setting it in the CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: I know we can specify the compiler by setting this variable, but what I want to do is rather to modify the default sequence that cmake searches for available compilers if the user does not say explicitly which compiler they want to use. For example, if the system has both ifort and gfortran, I want cmake to choose, when the user does not say otherwise, ifort instead of gfortran, which is the default behavior.